# GKE Node Pool status stuck as PROVISIONING

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create GKE Node Pool with Terraform

```
resource "google_container_node_pool" "node_pool" {
  provider = google-beta
  name       = var.node_pool_name
  location   = var.region
  cluster    = var.cluster_name
  node_count = var.k8s_workers_count

  node_config {
    machine_type = var.k8s_workers_shape

    image_type      = "COS"
    service_account = google_service_account.sa.email
    labels = {
      name = var.node_pool_name
    }
    metadata = {
      disable-legacy-endpoints = "true"
    }
    workload_metadata_config {
      node_metadata = "GKE_METADATA_SERVER"
    }
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
    ]
  }

  management {
    auto_repair  = true
    auto_upgrade = true
  }
}
```

After 3m TF console returning error message

```
Error: Error reading NodePool "pool1" from cluster "cluster-1": Nodepool "pool1" has status "PROVISIONING" with message ""
```

Gcloud cli returns that status indeed PROVISIONING

```
config:
  diskSizeGb: 100
  diskType: pd-standard
  imageType: COS
  labels:
    name: pool1
  machineType: n1-standard-4
  metadata:
    disable-legacy-endpoints: 'true'
  oauthScopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
  serviceAccount: 
  shieldedInstanceConfig:
    enableIntegrityMonitoring: true
initialNodeCount: 2
instanceGroupUrls:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/
management:
  autoRepair: true
  autoUpgrade: true
maxPodsConstraint:
  maxPodsPerNode: '110'
name: pool1
podIpv4CidrSize: 24
selfLink: XXX
status: PROVISIONING
version: 1.13.11-gke.14
```

However console.cloud.google.com showing that status is green, and cluster allows me to create deployments etc. Any thoughts, Cloud Heroes?

UPDATE: 1:48PM 12/7/2019 - I was able to run TF script. Not sure if Google fixed it or I just got lucky.

Comment: I'm having the same issue since yesterday...

Comment: same here for europe west 2

Comment: did you guys managed to solve the problem? i'm getting the same thing too

Comment: I am also got the same problem today. Until now, still facing the same problem. Mine in asia-southeast1 region

Comment: Thank for replies, guys. At least we all know that we are not alone :)

Comment: I'm reaching out to the support team for more details. Will let you know as soon as I know more.

Comment: So glad to stumble across this, I also noticed GCP status was all green and assumed we were doing something wrong. us-west1 for us

Answer (score 5):

There is some information about this issue on https://status.cloud.google.com/:

> Newly created GKE node pools in asia-east1-a, asia-east2-c, asia-northeast1-a, asia-northeast2-c, asia-south1-a, asia-southeast1-a, australia-southeast1-a, europe-north1-c, europe-west1-c, europe-west2-a, europe-west3-a, europe-west4-a, europe-west6-c, northamerica-northeast1-c, southamerica-east1-a, us-central1-b, us-east1-a, us-east1-d, us-east2-a, us-east4-b, us-west1-a and us-west2-c are created successfully but incorrectly shown as PROVISIONING. A rollback underway will resolve this for new node pools.